# How do we obtain $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$ from $f(x,y)$?

Tags: differential

**See this:** [What is the Jacobian, how does it work, and what is an intuitive explanation of the Jacobian and a change of basis?](https://qr.ae/TUn71x)

> Consider a function $f(x,y)$. The differential $df$ is given by: $df =
>  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$
>   This looks a lot like the **gradient** equation: $\nabla f =
>  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} {i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}{ j}$
>
> This is the basic idea behind the Jacobian (and differential forms) -
>   that **a differential can be viewed as a sort of vector**, with its
>   components being given by the partial derivative terms and the
>   **‘basis’** as the differentials of the independent variables - $dx$ and $dy$.
>   ... ...

How did he obtain: 
$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$ ?

Comment: See [The Chain Rule for Functions of Two Variables](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/chain/chain.html).

Comment: What do $df, dx$ and $dy$ _mean_ to you? After considering that, maybe your problem is actually obvious? If not, then at least you have a much more concrete question to work on.

Comment: The [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) is based on the principle of *composition* of functions. We have a function $f(x,y)$ and in turn $x$ and $y$ are function of a parameter $t$. What we have is : $f(x(t), y(t))$. Thus, in order to compute $\dfrac {df}{dt}$ we have to apply the rule.

Comment: More or less the same thing was asked just a few hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056517/how-total-derivative-of-a-function-works-and-what-is-the-derivation-of-the-formu